# Combining JS object keys

Tags: javascript

I want to combine keys without overwriting the original.
Previously, I had issues with .assign considering some keys are overwritten.

Example of what I'd like:

In:

```
a = {
first: [1, 2, 3],
second: [5]
}

b = {
first: [5],
second: [6, 7, 8]
}
```

Out:

```
{
first: [1, 2, 3, 5],
second: [5, 6, 7, 8]
}
```

What I've tried:

```
const c = {...a, ...b}
```

And:

```
Object.assign(a, b);
```

These look to produce similar if not same results.

Lastly:

```
concat()
```

But I may have not used the syntax correctly and wasn't able to get a result.

Comment: What's the pattern here? It's not clear where these two `5` entries are going. Is this just condensing the `values` of each object together?

Comment: You can use `concat()` to combine two arrays.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you've tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Try `concat` as mentoind by @Barmar, or you can use `spread operator` to spread contents to a new array.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in `assign` or `spread` or so for what you're trying to achieve here.

You have to do it explicitly. Like this, for example:

```js
const a = {
  first: [1, 2, 3],
  second: [5]
}

const b = {
  first: [5],
  second: [6, 7, 8]
}

// I want a new Object ...
const out = {
  // with a property "first", that consists of 
  // the items in `a.first` followed by them in `b.first`
  first: [...a.first, ...b.first],
  // and the same for the property "second"
  second: [...a.second, ...b.second],
}

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a generic case:

```js
//all objects
const objs = [
  {first: [1, 2, 3], second:[5]},
  {first: [5], second: [6, 7, 8]},
  {first: [3, 4], second: [5, 6]}
]

//unique keys
const unique_keys = new Set([].concat.apply([],objs.map(Object.keys)));

//unified object
const unified_obj = [...unique_keys].reduce((o, key) => {
    o[key] = objs.map(e => e[key]).reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e), []);
    return o;
}, {});
```

To get unique keys it's a bit more complex than `Object.keys(Object.assign(...objs))`, but performs better, as it doesn't deal with values at all.